# How can I solve this intial value problem?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How can I solve this IVP, 1st order differntial equation.

$$\frac{dy}{dt}= \frac {1}{e^y-t}$$

with initial value $y(1)=0?$

any help will be apperciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By solving for the inverse function $t(y)$. Then the problem becomes

$$\frac{dt}{dy} = e^y-t$$

or

$$\frac{dt}{dy} + t = e^y \; .$$

Multiplying both sides by $e^y$

$$e^y \frac{dt}{dy} + e^y t = e^{2y} \; ,$$

and noting that the left hand side is the derivative of $e^y t$, we get

$$\frac{d}{dy}\left( e^y t \right)= e^{2y} \; ,$$

and integrating with respect to $y$ this becomes

$$e^y t = \frac{1}{2}e^{2y} + C \; .$$

Rearranging this, we arrive at

$$t=\frac{1}{2}e^y-C e^{-y} \; .$$

For your initial condition, this gives $t=\cosh(y)$ or

$$y=\cosh^{-1}(t) \; .$$

Comment: @Rasholnikov : Yeah this makes sense, but could you please explain how you divided every variable where it belongs before the second step?

Comment: @binarylife: is this more like it?

Comment: Yes this is very helpful , Thank you so much ! , I was stuck.

Answer (score 5):

Substituting $y = u + \ln t$ gives
$$
\frac{du}{dt} + \frac{1}{t} \;=\; \frac{1}{t e^u - t}
$$
which is a separable equation.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion , I will try it though.